# Having trouble with Jquery Focus()

Tags: jquery, focus

I am trying to set focus on a link button inside of an overlay when the overlay trigger is clicked. Here's the code:

```
$('.enroll-trigger, .nav-open-an-account').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    enrollTabPos = 0;
    $('#window-outer, body').removeClass('nav-open');
    $('#mobile-menu-toggle').removeClass('active');
    $('#top-nav > ul > li').removeClass('active');
    $('#mobile-nav > ul > li').removeClass('active');
    $('#internal-nav > ul > li').removeClass('active');
    $('body').removeClass('login-overlay-open ext-overlay-open'); 
    $('body').toggleClass('enroll-overlay-open');
    $('#openaccount-checking').focus();                

});
```

For some reason the last line with the focus command is not working. I can click the trigger element and everything else that is supposed to happen happens except for the focus change. I have similar focus changes on other overlay triggers in thr page and they work, so I'm at a loss for why this one doesn't. I checked the id, and it is correct. Can anyone take a look and tell me what is going on? You can view the site at http://investar.meshbr.com and the trigger in question is the Open an Account button in the top nav.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Did you try `.triggerHandler( "focus" )` on this? - .focus() only works on visible elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are using code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {})`?
Because this not load if you are outside.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your website and Open an Account button click event. There is something wrong with your JS referenced for the popup having **checking** option. Therefore it not working.

Please check this line **this.popupMenu.open();** in your JS "MenuBarItemLink.JS" at line 175 and 180. There might be Show() property work for it on line 175.

Comment: Hi Tapendra, thanks for pointing this out. I see what the issue is there, unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be the culprit for the focus problem because even if I disable that script entirely, the focus commend still doesn't work. The reason the popupMenuOpen is firing is an error is because my cms code has a glitch that is outputting code saying that some of the menu items have children when they really don't and the MenuBarItemLink js file thinks they have children because of this and is trying to open submenus that don't exist. I turned that off , but the focus problem is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the original poster solved the issue by wrapping the `focus()` in a `setTimeout` to delay its execution.

So this line:

```
$('#openaccount-checking').focus();
```

Becomes this:

```
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('#openaccount-checking').focus();
    }, 500);
```